# Play Games works sometimes

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

I added Google Play Games to my Android game. Sometimes when I start the game it shows a pop up with something like `Welcome Player!` and sometimes it doesn't. This is the same for achievements. It sometimes pops up like `Achievement unlocked`, and sometimes it doesn't.

In Google Play Developer Console, I see that I have published my settings, but I don't see any users, although it had been working a few times.

In Play Games, I see my game, but I see only two tabs (about and players). I don't see my achievements, nor my leaderboard there.

Any ideas?

**Update: Achievements are working, but Leaderboard is not**

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your inquiry about Achievements unlocked, you have to call '*unlock()*' method to unlock achievement. You do not need to write additional code to unlock the achievement. Google Play Games services will automatically unlocks the achievement.
To show a player's achievements, you may use '*getAchievementsIntent()'* method to get an Intent to create the default achievements UI. Your game can then bring up the UI by calling *startActivityForResult*.

To create or edit achievements and leaderboards, click the Achievements and Leaderboards tabs for your game from the Google Play Developer Console and fill out the corresponding forms.

For more information regarding Android Games Achievements, follow this link: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/achievements

Comment: Thank you, but achievements are working now. However, the Leaderboard is not.

Answer (score 1):

Same as Achievements, before you begin you must define the leaderboards that you want your game to display or update. You may check your Google Play Developer Console.

Once the player is signed in and the '*GoogleAPIClient*' is connected, your game can start using the leaderboards API's.

To display a leaderboard, call the *startActivityForResult* and pass in the intent to create the default leaderboard UI. In the following code snippet, *REQUEST_LEADERBOARD* is an arbitrary integer for the request code.

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,
    LEADERBOARD_ID), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
```

Comment: When will the Leaderboards tab appear in Google Play Games?